# What is the class hierarchy/call chain in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hag")?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the class hierarchy/call chain in the right side of the following assignment?

```
byte[] data= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hag");
```

My current understanding is this:

> **UTF8** is a static property of the abstract **Encoding** class. This property instantiates and returns an object of type
>   **System.Text.UTF8Encoding** . This object has a method called **GetBytes()** which is an overridden version of Encoding.GetBytes().

1) Is the above statement correct?

2) If the above statement is correct, is it common to use a static property to instantiate an object? (Is it the same as factory method pattern)?

Comment: You missed activation of type initializers aka static constructors, if any exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So you mean in the static constructor of Encoding, the object has been created?

Comment: I mean when you access the `UTF8` property, before the property getter runs, the class's static constructor runs.  Either or both of those could be involved in creating the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the class hierarchy/call chain in the right side of the following assignment?

It's equivalent to:

```
Encoding e = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] data= e.GetBytes("hag");
```

> Is the above statement correct?

Yes

> is it common to use a static property to instantiate an object?

Well, it's not really *instantiating* an object - the object already exists, you're just using a static *reference* to it.  But yes, using a static property to expose a finite set of easily categorizable class instances is a common practice.  Look at the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, for example.

**EDIT**

I think I understand your question better - the property is instantiating an object *the first time the getter is called*.  After that, it returns *the same instance* on subsequent gets.

> Is it the same as factory method pattern

It's similar, the factory pattern would look more like

```
Encoding.GetEncoder("UTF8").GetBytes("hag");
```

The factory pattern typically produces multiple instances of a single type (although some factories will re-use instances).

Comment: So where the object has been instantiated?

Comment: In the `Encoding` class it's instantiated the first time the property is called.  In other classes they may be instantiated in the static constructor.

Comment: More details or rather verification: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs#a10eb90a3d884500

Comment: @floele: Wow... it is exactly what I wanted! awesome.

Comment: Hm should I have made an answer out of that? Looks like I'm missing reputation here ;)

Comment: @floele: Yes. I wish you had put it in an answer. Even now, it would get more attention if you do that.

Comment: @kami Be aware that the actual place the object is created is an _implementation detail_ that could change.  Although I don't know why it matters to you _when_ the object is created, unless you're just curious.

Comment: I guess I'll do, I could still get an upvote at least :)

Answer (score 1):

For questions like this, you can check the recently updated [.NET reference source website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com). Searching for "encoding.utf8" (yes, this works) yields the [source code that shows the actual construction](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=encoding.utf8):

```
private static volatile Encoding utf8Encoding;
public static Encoding UTF8 
{
     get 
     {
         if (utf8Encoding == null) 
             utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true);
         return utf8Encoding;
     }
}
```

It might also be interesting to note that `Encoding.GetEncoding("...")` [actually returns the `UTF8` property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs#463) if you call it wuth "utf8".